send keys in cypress while running in linux container
I need to clear the content of the element , i am using the following logic
if (Cypress.platform == "darwin") {
  cy.get(".view-lines").type("{cmd}A{del}");
} else {
    cy.log("inside different OS")
    cy.get(".view-lines").type("{ctrl}A{del}");
}

Its working fine in Mac where I am developing the script , but its not working in testbed where the automation is running which is "linux"
Is there any alternative for ctrl+a+del in linux..?
I have tried with different cypress ways to clear the element , which is not working. and eventually worked only with cmd+a+del in mac .

The type() command can only be used on editable elements, see Supported Elements. You can also try to force it - .type('{selectall}{del}', {force:true}). Lastly, since the element is a <div> you can try .click() before the .type(), this may add the contenteditable attribute and allow .type() to work.

Sometimes modifiers like {ctrl} don't works, but in this case you can use the {selectAll} modifier.
Take a look at the Cypress test type_special_chars.cy.js
context('{selectall}{del}', () => {
  it('can select all the text and delete', () => {
    cy.get(':text:first').invoke('val', '1234')
      .type('{selectall}{del}')
      .type('foo').then(($text) => {
        expect($text).to.have.value('foo')
      })
  })

or just use the .clear() command
cy.get(':text:first')
  .invoke('val', '1234')
  .should('have.value', '1234')
  .clear()
  .should('have.value', '')


I am not able to use the clear as this particular element in on div and clear gives the error "cy.clear() failed because it requires a valid clearable element"
And I tried {selectall} as well , that also not working.

Problem for me here is , {ctrl}A{del} not working out in linux where in the mac its working.  is there any different key combinations I can try out for linux..?

Thanks for the further information. The error you get from cy.clear() indicates that this issue is not the keys used but the element you are trying to clear. Basically, it is not an <input> or a <textarea> element.

There are a couple of work-arounds. Please add details of the HTML you are testing and I'll post appropriate details.
